# Abstract methods in typescript mixins

Tags: typescript, abstract, mixins

I want a Typescript Mixin to have an abstract method that's implemented by the mixed-into class. Something like this.

```
class MyBase { 
}

type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function Mixin<TBase extends Constructor<MyBase>>(Base: TBase) {
  return class extends Base {

    baseFunc(s: string) {};

    doA()
    {
        this.baseFunc("A");
    }
  }
};

class Foo extends Mixin(MyBase) {
    constructor()
    {
      super();
    }

    baseFunc(s: string)
    {
      document.write("Foo "+ s +"...   ")            
    }
};
```

Now, this works, but I'd really like to make baseFunc in the mixin be abstract to ensure that it's implemented in Foo. Is there any way of doing this, as `abstract baseFunc(s:string);` says I must have an abstract class, which isn't allowed for mixins...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Anonymous class can not be abstract, but you still can declare local mixin class which is abstract like this:

```
class MyBase { 
}

type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function Mixin(Base: Constructor<MyBase>) {
  abstract class AbstractBase extends Base {
    abstract baseFunc(s: string);    
    doA()
    {
        this.baseFunc("A");
    }
  }
  return AbstractBase;
};


class Foo extends Mixin(MyBase) {
    constructor()
    {
      super();
    }

    baseFunc(s: string)
    {
      document.write("Foo "+ s +"...   ")            
    }
};
```

Comment: I thought I'd tried that! Why doesn't `return abstract class...` work? (edit - ah! because it's anonymous!)

Comment: This example loses the methods and properties of MyBase. You can fix with `function Mixin<B extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: B)`.